# there is no "create" button on the remix- why?

Tags: tokens, remix

Need help please- there is no "create" button on the remix- why? look at the attached image.
what should i do, to get the "create"

Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: There is no image attached to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Create` button was changed to `Deploy`.

You can find it under the `Run` tab at the top.

Comment: ok, got it, but where im placing the amount and and token name?

Comment: From the picture, there are a couple of things that could be the issue. Firstly, the constructor name doesn't match the contract name. (There's a lower-case "t".) But this is irrelevant because constructor functions have been deprecated - you should now use the `constructor  (<params>)` syntax. See: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html?highlight=constructor#creating-contracts

Comment: No problem - glad it helped :-)

Comment: If you don't mind, I have couple of questions for you here is my skype: boris.kasparov79